# I’m building a bot for vets to automate job applications

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, bots

I’m working with a veterans group to build a automation bot to complete job applications for veterans. We want them to come home to a great job and family. I’m struggling with completing this because I can’t get selenium to map fields do to nothing being listed in elements.

Any ideas would be awesome

Comment: By "do to" do you mean "due to"?

Comment: How about the idea to avoid trying to get selenium to map fields in case nothing is listed in elements?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.